# Devexpress document viewer fill page to conatiner

Tags: devexpress, documentviewer, picturefill

I have DevExpress raport.cs and DocumentViewer container. I want how fill displayed page to container?

[image]

Comment: If I understand the question, you need to fill the whole page space? So try in the Report Designer modify Margins.
Or please better describe what do you need to do.

Comment: I use devexpress controls. I make with this report and put DocumentViewer on Form1.  DocumentViewer.DocumentSource = Xraport. Document viewer take half size of form1.  But i need see full report in this size of DocumentViewer.
Something like fill to page in printer :)

Comment: I need auto match report size to DocumentViewer size. 1 to 1 / 1:1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner.XRDesignPanel and put it to TableLayout or other container and than use it :

```
xrdpReport.Visible = false;                                
xrdpReport.BeginInit();                                
xrdpReport.OpenReport(report);//Inherited from DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport
xrdpReport.EndInit();
xrdpReport.Visible = true;
```

and after start the application you will see something like this (you can hide the upper toolbar)

[image: Page for printer in Form]

Comment: This report is not filled only his parent. When you fill report  you cant have scroll bars. :) I need auto match size to DocumentViewer size. 1 to 1 / 1:1

Comment: I think that no DevExpress component can do it. When printing you always choose the size / dimensions of the paper ... Maybe make a PrintScreen of report and then resize it, but it's pretty crazy solutions.

Comment: I dont belive there is no way to auto size  content to container.